# Samsung SyncMaster 2443BWX LCD flickers, flashes, fades out

Tags: dell-latitude, performance-monitor

I have a Samsung SyncMaster 2443BWX LCD monitor hooked up to my Dell Latitude E6410 laptop through the dock. The monitor sometimes would flicker, flash, fade out. It happens very randomly. Sometime the monitor could go for days without a problem, sometime it happens daily. Is it because my Dell laptop's GPU can not handle the monitor? I also have another Dell monitor extended too.

Thanks

Comment: Pho, more details please… for example, when you plug the samsung monitor *directly" into your laptop, do you have the same problem?

Comment: if possible, borrow someone else's (known to be working) monitor and plug it into your dock and see if you can reproduce the problem. Doing this and the above will determine if it is the monitor, dock, or gpu. Thanks.